# Whats wrong with the writing to this file handle?

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fpin = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    fprintf(fpin, "hello, world!");
    fclose (fpin);

    char c;
    fpin = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    FILE *fpout = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    while ((c = fgetc(fpin)) != EOF) {
        fputc (toupper(c), fpout);
    }

    fclose (fpout);
    fclose (fpin);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a

> Segmentation fault

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I dont know anything about C, but is seems that you write to a file that you have opened read-only ...

```
FILE *fpin = fopen("in.txt", "r"); 
fprintf(fpin, "hello, world!");
```

should probably be :

```
FILE *fpin = fopen("in.txt", "w"); 
fprintf(fpin, "hello, world!");
```

Comment: And if that's not the segv, you're not checking the return value of the second fopen so since the first doesn't create it, the second will fail and you'll have a NULL pointer in fpin...

Answer (score 4):

They first issues that I see is that you don't check for the success of the `fopen` call.  It can fail and cause `fpin` to be NULL which would lead to issues later on in the code.

```
FILE *fpin = fopen("in.txt", "r"); 
if (!fpin) { 
  printf("Error opening in.txt");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Change your `char c;` to `int c;` -- `fgetc` returns an int.
2. Check the return value of calls to `fopen` to see if you get a NULL return.
3. Change the mode of the first `fopen` to `"w"` so you can write to the file.
4. You may want to consider adding a `\n` to the end of `"hello world!"`.

Comment: +1: And I'd also add: 5. compile with all warnings on; 6. If you ask questions on SO give a more precise description of the error (in which line did your error occur...)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, one of your `fopen` calls is failing and returning `NULL`. The most likely candidate for this is the following line:

```
FILE *fpin = fopen("in.txt", "r");
```

You probably meant to use a `"w"` here, as you later try to write to the file. I'm guessing the file doesn't exist yet... and hence, when you try to open it with `"r"`, the `fopen` call fails.